# Как отсортировать данные из БД перед выводом в TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

Как отсортировать данные из БД перед выводом в TextView
 Данные выводятся с помощью адаптера

при использовании "DESC" нету результата почемуто

пример используемого кода

вставка===========

```
 public long createNote(String title, String body, String date) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title); 
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); 

}
```

============= а это извлечение

```
  <i>
   String orderBy = "DESC";
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
</i>
```

---

Но  "DESC" почему-то не сортирует

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8948476/3212712) в запросе надо уточнить по какой колонке надо сотрировать, добавив её перед указанием способа сортировки:

т.е. вместо

> String orderBy = "DESC";

надо

```
String orderBy = yourColumn + " DESC";
```

Comment: если применяю      String orderBy = KEY_ROWID + "DESC";   
 то получаю при запуске  Unfortunately,NoteList has stoped

Comment: @mtb, вы словили какую-то ошибку. Без указания её типа помочь вам никто не сможет. Проверьте что вы подставили точное имя колонки.

Comment: KEY_ROWID  содержит  _id     - но вот почему он не работатет как-то странно

Comment: @mtb, Ну, может быть его надо какими нибудь кавычками окружить... Что-то типа `"\`_id\` DESC"`

Comment: @mtb Думаю, надо пробел добавить перед DESC - " DESC", а не "DESC"

Comment: @pavlofff, в моих примерах так и есть, но, видать, не помогает...

Comment: В вашем примере так, а [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473769/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-textview/473775?noredirect=1#comment534262_473775) не так (первый комент под вашим ответом)

Comment: @pavlofff, действительно) Подождём ТС - может он вернётся, прочитает комменты и чего нам расскажет)